# How to define type or interface for dynamic object?

Tags: typescript

Let's suppose that I have the following code:

```js
interface ItemsByKeyInterface {}
interface AType {
  key: number;
  label: string;
}

const array: AType[] = [
  { key: "a", label: "1" },
  { key: "b", label: "2" }
];

const itemsByKey: ItemsByKeyInterface = array.reduce((total, item) => {
  return {
    ...total,
    [item.key]: item
  };
}, {});
```

How should I define `ItemsByKeyInterface` properly?
Consider that AType could be anything (anything with a key property) and the array could have an unlimited and unknown number of items (consider that key would be unique in that array)

```js
const p = itemsByKey.b.label;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this

```js
interface ItemsByKeyInterface {
  [key: number]: Item;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to write something like 'const p = itemsByKey.b.label;'. Is it possible to define an interface to do that?